# Grand Prix in Mathematics of the French Academy of Sciences

Tags: mathematics

I'm interested in the mathematical problems proposed for the grand-prix
of the French Academy Of Sciences, from its beginnigs in 1666 to the present.
Are there any books or articles with the precise problem statements & the winners?

Answer (score 7):

Ernest Maindron, [Les fondations de prix à l’Académie des sciences: Les lauréats de l’Académie, 1714–1880](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k97893365). Gauthier-Villars, Paris, 1881.

It is striking and not well-enough known (e.g. to Wikipedia) how the huge **125,000 pounds** endowed in 1714 by [Rouillé de Meslay](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Baptiste_Rouill%C3%A9_de_Meslay) (compare £20,000 for the famous [Longitude Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_rewards) drafted by [Newton](http://books.google.com/books?id=LQxDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA677)) drove fame and focus to celestial mechanics (for navigation, mostly even years) and shipbuilding (odd years) in 18th century science and technology, until the French Revolution:

`Year:                                                                    Winners:
1720  Nature of motion                                                     Crousaz
1720  Clock stabilization at sea                                             Massy
1724  Collision laws                                      Mac Laurin, J. Bernoulli
1725  Hourglass and water clock stabilization at sea                  D. Bernoulli
1726  Collision laws                                                       Mazière
1727  Ship masting                                               Bouguer, Le Camus
1728  Causes of gravity                                                 Bulffinger
1729  Height measurement at sea                                            Bouguer
1730  Motion of planetary aphelia                                     J. Bernoulli
1731  Compass use at sea                                                   Bouguer
1732  Tilting of planetary orbits                                                ∅
1733  Ship path tracing                                                     Poleni
1734  Tilting of planetary orbits                       D. Bernoulli, J. Bernoulli
1736  Propagation of light                                            J. Bernoulli
1737  Anchor design          Créqui, Poleni, Trésaguet, D. Bernoulli, J. Bernoulli
1738  Nature and propagation of fire            Créqui, Lozeran de Fiesc, L. Euler
1740  Tides                          Cavalleri, Mac Laurin, L. Euler, D. Bernoulli
1741  Capstan building      de Pontis, Fenel, Delorme, Poleni, Ludot, J. Bernoulli
1743  Compass building                                      L. Euler, D. Bernoulli
1746  Compass magnetism               Dutour, L. Euler, D. Bernoulli, J. Bernoulli
1747  Finding time at sea                                             D. Bernoulli
1748  Inequalities of Saturn and Jupiter                                  L. Euler
1750  Inequalities of Saturn and Jupiter                                         ∅
1751  Estimation of currents at sea                                   D. Bernoulli
1752  Inequalities of Saturn and Jupiter                        Bošković, L. Euler
1753  Ship propulsion           Mathon de la Cour, Pereyre, L. Euler, D. Bernoulli
1754  Planetary perturbations of Earth                                           ∅
1755  Ship pitch and roll                                                 Chauchot
1756  Planetary perturbations of Earth                                    L. Euler
1757  Ship pitch and roll                                             D. Bernoulli
1758  Celestial body atmospheres                                             Frisi
1759  Ship pitch and roll                                      Groignard, L. Euler
1760  Mean motion of planets                                       Frisi, C. Euler
1761  Ship stowage and ballasting                              Bossut, J. A. Euler
1762  Lunar acceleration                                                    Bossut
1764  Lunar libration                                                     Lagrange
1765  Ship stowage and ballasting  Bourdé de Villehuet, Groignard, Gautier, Bossut
1766  Satellites of Jupiter                                               Lagrange
1768  Secular equation of the Moon                                               ∅
1769  Timekeeping at sea                                                    Le Roy
1770  Secular equation of the Moon                           J. A. Euler, L. Euler
1772  Secular equation of the Moon                              Lagrange, L. Euler
1773  Timekeeping at sea                                        Arsandeaux, Le Roy
1774  Secular equation of the Moon                                        Lagrange
1776  Planetary perturbations of comets                                          ∅
1777  Compass building                                 Magny, Van Swinden, Coulomb
1778  Planetary perturbations of comets                                       Fuss
1780  Planetary perturbations of comets                                   Lagrange
1781  Rope stiffness and friction in winches Delanges, Ximenes, L. Carnot, Coulomb
1782  Comets of 1532 and 1661                                              Méchain
1787  Maritime insurance                                     Bicquilley, Delacroix
1791  Resistance of fluids                                          Gerlach, Romme
1791  Herschel’s planet                                                   Delambre
1792  Satellites of Jupiter                                               Delambre`

More details in:
Frédéric Marguet, [Histoire générale de la navigation du XV<sup>e</sup> au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle](https://web.archive.org/web/20130328041503/http://hydro.marseille.free.fr:80/histoire_nav_marguet/histoire_nav_marguet.htm). Société d’Éditions Géographiques, Maritimes et Coloniales, Paris, 1931.

Comment: Very nice! But what about after 1880?

Comment: I don’t know. Start [here](http://www.academie-sciences.fr/en/Overview/awards-and-medals.html)?

Comment: I wanted to add one point for the addition of Marguet, but somehow the system does not allow it. I was under impression that after a an answer was edited I can vote once more.

Comment: It seems that from the pure utilitarian view the British had better return on their money:-)

Comment: For sure, their navy ended up trouncing the rest of them, and they got an empire. But I remember reading that Harrison’s clocks long remained so expensive that in practice most ships used the lunar distance method, based on the work of Euler and Mayer. Also, I believe the French prizes only spent the interest of the original fund, not the capital (which only later got lost to inflation or political turmoil). And today *we* do use celestial navigation — only with *ad hoc* satellites (GPS). (P.S. I appreciate your generous intent :-))

Answer (score 1):

The first prize winning essays are available in full via Google Books in *Pieces qui ont remporte les deux prizes de l'Academie Royale des Sciences* (Paris 1721). Hope your 18th century French is up to scratch!